# Как прописать css блоку так, что бы текст не наезжал и при этом текст нормально отражался

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  width: 300px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 230px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.bott {
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background: #33C1E3;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.circle {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #BABABA;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: -70px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.circle img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.a1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.text {
  padding-top: 90px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title> Hello </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main circle">
    <img src="3751323.jpeg" alt=""> </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Приветствую</p>
      <p>Приветствую</p>

    </div>

    <div class="bott">
      <div class="a1">
        <a href="#">Перейти на сайт</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

как сделать так что бы текст блока не уезжал под другой блок?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш пример не переделывал а показал Вам мою версию

Если что то не ясно спрашивайте

https://jsfiddle.net/lenskyuser/sg6dvabp/30/  здесь можно увидеть мою тренировку с разным количеством текста

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  html,body{
  height:100%;
  }

.items {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.view {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.view img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateY(-25px);
  text-align: center;
}

.view_footer {
  background: #33C1E3;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.view_footer a {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">


  <div class="item">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://user.mistaua.com/avatar/2015/24074_1_1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, quo.
      </div>
      <div class="view_footer">
        <a href="#">перейти на сайт</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000144644493-i5i4hu-large.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, quo.
      </div>
      <div class="view_footer">
        <a href="#">перейти на сайт</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="http://wallpaperstock.ru/cache/8047379b27cf9ebeab9d8ccb7f62c356_100x100x0.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, quo.
      </div>
      <div class="view_footer">
        <a href="#">перейти на сайт</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="view">
      <img src="https://ru-static.z-dn.net/files/dbf/b32be1a763ebdf25a962bac6019ef4c8.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, quo.
      </div>
      <div class="view_footer">
        <a href="#">перейти на сайт</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: нужно что бы в высоту только растягивался

Comment: на jsfiddle растягивается

Answer (score 0):

У вас .main ограничен выстой (height: 230px). Увеличьте его.

Comment: а если по макету он именно такого размера,тогда как исправить?

Comment: Смотря чем готовы «пожертвовать». Меньше текста, меньше отступы, кегль мельче.